# Swift: Create an Overlay

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm making an ios app in swift, taking a programatic approach (not using Storyboards). How can I add an overlay image to the app such that it doesn't go away when the current view controller is changed? This is similar to having a progress bar on the bottom of a music app that doesn't disappear when you look through various pages in the app (i.e. changing from one playlist page to another playlist page). Thanks!

Comment: Use a root view controller that has your overlay and a container view. Swap out the content in the container view

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work. Do I need for my root view controller to call `present` with the new desired view controller, and then to call `view.addSubview` with the overlay?

Comment: No,  you use `addChildViewController`.  Apple has some documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html  It talks about storyboards, but you can do it without.  It is just easier (IMO) with a storyboard

Comment: Thank you! I ended up figuring that out a couple of minutes before you commented, but this works perfectly!

Comment: How can I present other controllers on top of the child controller? Doing so now causes the new controller to cover the whole screen.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use the standard present/dismiss.  You have to use `addChildController` and `removeFromParentViewController`; The steps for showing a new VC and removing a VC in a container are here:https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html